# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, eclipse, fórmulas-de-matriz

alguien me puede ayudar con este problema? cree este sencillo ejemplo para poner a prueba lo que aprendí hace poco en programación en java, pero por alguna razón cuando intento ejecutar el problema me da error aun que no tenga ninguna parte señalada, alguien me puede ayudar?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] hembra = new String[2];

        String macho[] = new String[2];

        macho[0] = "macho";
        macho[1] = "Hombre";
        macho[2] = "masculino";
        hembra[0] = "hembra";
        hembra[1] = "mujer";
        hembra[2] = "femenino";

        String genero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu genero");

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            if (genero.equals(hembra[i])) {

                String altura = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu altura en cm");

                int peso1 = Integer.parseInt(altura);

                System.out.println("tu peso ideal es: " + (peso1 - 120) + "kilos");

            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
            if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase(macho[a])) {
                String altura2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu altura en cm");

                int peso2 = Integer.parseInt(altura2);

                System.out.println("tu peso ideal es: " + (peso2 - 110) + "kilos");

            }

            if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase(hembra[a])) {
                String altura3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce tu altura en cm");
                int peso3 = Integer.parseInt(altura3);
                System.out.println("tu peso isea es: " + (peso3 - 120) + " Kilos");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas compañero @NoelSan el error que te emite te indica que estas tratando de acceder a un indice de tu array que sobrepase al la cantidad que el mismo posee, esto ocurre aqui `macho[2] = "masculino";` y `hembra[2] = "femenino";` ya que se definio `String[] hembra = new String[2];` y `String macho[] = new String[2];` eso quiere decir que tienes dos valores de inidice la posicion `[0]` y la `[1]`, si quieres la posicion `[2]` debes definir tus array con 3 valores algo asi  como `String macho[] = new String[3];`

Comment: @Nicethunder muchas gracias, empeze a usar las matrices sin darme cuenta de ese detalle, enserio muchas gracias, ya me estaba rallando xD

Comment: @AndoniAlda tan solo quería hacer un sencillo código donde aceptara todos los sinónimos de esas dos palabras, para asi no limitar al usuario a la hora de responder :p no hace falta que le hagas mucho caso ya que es solo una prueba :u

Comment: Al declarar el array estas creandolo con 2 posiciones y estas intentando guardar en una tercera posición un valor.

Comment: recuerda que los arrays siempre empiezan con _índice_ **0**

Answer (score 0):

Bueno como te comentaron los companeros tu problema esta en el tamaño que le defines al array ya que tu necesitas un array de tamaño 3 y no de 2.

```
    String[] hembra = new String[3];

    String[] macho = new String[3];
```

Ademas deberias cambiar los rangos del for para que recorra los 3 elementos por array.

En tu caso te recomendaria que los arreglos los inicializaras directamente y para evitar estar definidiendo el tamaño podrias recorrer claramamente el array con un foreach

```
    String[] macho = {"macho","hombre","masculino"};

    String[] hembra = {"hembra","mujer","femenino"};

    for(String genero: macho){
        //stuff
    }

    for(String genero: hembra){
        //stuff
    }
```